# MySQL Query to XQuery

Tags: mysql, xml, xquery, xquery-sql

I'm trying to get the equivalent of the following MySQL Query to an XQuery

```
SELECT S.Classification, COUNT(S.Classification) AS "No. Students", AVG(S.GPA) AS "AVG
    Class. GPA"
FROM Student S
GROUP BY S.Classification
ORDER BY S.Classification ASC;
```

This outputs:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu0d4.png

Where My Database looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE 'Student' (
'StudentID' CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
'Classification' CHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
'GPA` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
'MentorID' CHAR(9) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
'CreditHours' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ('StudentID')
)
```

And in XML:

```
<Document>
  <Table>
    <StudentID>118784412</StudentID>
    <Classification>Sophomore</Classification>
    <GPA>3.19</GPA>
    <MentorID>201586985</MentorID>
    <CreditHours>39</CreditHours>
  </Table>
</Document>
```

I'm not sure how to use the count() and avg() in xquery.
Where do I start? Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: What is your XQuery processor? Group by is not explicitly supported in XQuery 1.0. It is in 1.1 and 3.0, but not many implementations currently support those specs. There are implementation-specific extensions and workarounds, however. Also XSLT 2 is a good option for group by if you can use it. The ideal solution will depend on these variables.

Comment: XQuery 1.0. I know I cannot use 'group by'.

Comment: What xQuery processor are you using? The optimal group by solution will be implementation specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this using the group by operator defined in XQuery 3.0. Assuming the given xml is in the variable `$doc` and each and every row of the database is in another `<Table />` node, you can do it like this:

```
for $student in $doc/Table
let $classification := $student/Classification
group by $classification
order by $classification
return 
  <output>
    <Classification>{$classification}</Classification>
    <NoStudents>{count($student)}</NoStudents>
    <AvgGPA>{avg($student/GPA)}</AvgGPA>
  </output>
```

There are a number of (excellent) XQuery processors supporting XQuery 3.0, e.g. [BaseX](http://www.basex.org), [eXist](http://exist-db.org/) and [Zorba](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/)

Comment: I don't think I can 'group by'. I tried that and got an error, therefore I don't think I'm able to use XQuery 3.0.

Comment: What processor are your using?